# Submit a form inside another form submit event via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, form-submit

I have two forms on one page. When I click on submit button of parent form, parent form submit event is called where I wrote the logic to submit the second form with the help of submit method (see below code). The problem is when the second form submit method called, it gets the page reload automatically before submitting the parent form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aspnetForm").submit(function(event) {               
        debugger;
        var marketoForm = MktoForms2.allForms()[0];
        console.log(marketoForm);
        marketoForm.addHiddenFields({
        //These are the values which will be submitted to Marketo
        "Email": $('#MainContentPlaceHolder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C006_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write').val(),
        "FirstName": $('#MainContentPlaceHolder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C001_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write').val(),
        "LastName": $('#MainContentPlaceHolder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C005_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write').val(),
        "Phone": $('#MainContentPlaceHolder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_C012_ctl00_ctl00_textBox_write').val(),
        "MarketoSocialGender": $('#MainContentPlaceHolder_C003_ctl00_ctl00_ctl06_C051_ctl00_ctl00_dropDown').val()
        });             
        marketoForm.submit();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Html is like below -

```
<form method="post" action="./physical-therapy-test-by-rahul" id="aspnetForm">
    <form id="mktoForm_15528"></form>
</form>
```

Can someone please help why my page getting reload? How can I submit both forms on submitting the only first form?

Comment: Are your forms nested one inside the other? If so, that's an issue as you cannot do that, and your HTML will need to be corrected as it's invalid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, my forms are nested one inside another in HTML like this - <form method="post" action="./physical-therapy-test-by-rahul?aliId=66827066" id="aspnetForm">
 <form id="mktoForm_15528"></form>
</form>

Comment: Then that is part of your problem as it's not possible to do that. Could you please edit your question to include your HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the response. I have added a short HTML to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple forms nested like that.  When the marketo form is submitted, it is posting the internal form, and would post back to the server, unless you are capturing the form submit.  However, anything you add to the inner form would be available via the outer form.  If the `marketoForm.addHiddenFields()` method adds addition input fields, these fields would also be available in the asp.net form, which means the inner form could simply be a DIV that gets content added to.

Since fields are being dynamically added, it would require getting the value through `Request.Form("Email")` on the server.

ASP.NET web forms has some limitations that ASP.NET MVC eliminated; I don't know if that is another possibility.  OR, if you can submit the inner form via AJAX, and then trigger a post to the outer FORM, that could work (plus the inner form doesn't need to be a `<FORM>` tag, but a div seralized in a `$.ajax` call) as another option but I don't know the situation to know whether that will work.